# Google Chart Drilldown based on javascript search

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, graph

I have a javascript search bar. My output gets displayed in the table form and when I do a javascript search, it shows me the result of my search. I need my graph to also show only the result of the search when i do a search in the search bar.

```
    <body>
    <?php
    $colors = array('#e2431e', '#f1ca3a', '#6f9654', '#1c91c0','#4374e0', '#5c3292', '#572a1a', '#999999', '#1a1a1a','red','blue','yellow','green', 'darkgreen','pink');
    //initalizing the query
    $id =  $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM new_default_reports WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $row['sql_statement'] = stripslashes($row['sql_statement']);
?>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "<?php echo $row['graph_title']; echo ' - Update/Delete';?>",
                width: 800,
                height: 550,
                zIndex:'2000000'

            });
            $("#btnShow").click(function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            });
        });
    </script>

    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['set'])){
        $query = "UPDATE new_default_reports SET sql_statement ='{$_POST['sqlst']}', x_axis ='{$_POST['x']}', y_axis = '{$_POST['y']}' where id = $id";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        //header("Refresh: 0; url=previewgraphs.php?id=".$id);//not needed
        $id =  $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM new_default_reports WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $row['sql_statement'] = stripslashes($row['sql_statement']);
    }

    ?>
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['delete'])){

    $query = "UPDATE new_default_reports SET deleted = 1 where id = $id";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    header('Location: defaultreports.php');
    }
    ?>



    <br><input type="button" id="btnShow" class = "form-control" style="margin-top:12%;width:200px;border:2px solid darkgray;font-weight:bold;background-color:lightgray;" value="Edit Default Reports" />
    <div id="dialog" align="center">
    <form action = "" method="post">
        <label> SQL Statement</label>
        <textarea name="sqlst" style="width:100%;height:40%;" class = "form-control"><?php echo $row['sql_statement']?></textarea><br>
        <label> X axis: </label>
        <input type="text" name="x" class = "form-control" value="<?php echo $row['x_axis'] ?>"><br>
        <label> Y axis: </label>
        <input type="text" name="y" class = "form-control"  value="<?php echo $row['y_axis'] ?>"><br>
        <input type="submit" name = "set" value="Update" style="background-color:darkred;width:100px;color:white;font-weight:bold" />
        <input type="submit" name = "delete" class="classname" value = "DELETE">
    </form>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['notify'])){ ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            A New Graph <?php echo $row['graph_title']; ?> has been created.
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

            <?php
            $query = stripslashes($row['sql_statement']);
            $result = $conn_temp->query($query);
            //$row1 = $result->fetch_assoc();
            //generating graph now
            $x_axis = str_replace('`', '', $row['x_axis']);
            $y_axis = str_replace('`', '', $row['y_axis']);
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['corechart','wordtree','gantt']});

                // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
              google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

              function daysToMilliseconds(days) {
                return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
              }

              // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
              // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
              // draws it.

              function drawChart() {
                    // Create the data table.
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                    <?php if($row['type_of_graph']==6){ ?>
                        data.addColumn('string', '<?php echo $x_axis ?>');
                        data.addColumn('string', '<?php echo $y_axis ?>');
                        data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
                        data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
                        data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

                        data.addRows([
                            <?php
                            $temp = 'null';
                            $count = 1;
                            while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                                ?>
                                ['<?php echo $row1["$x_axis"] ?>','<?php echo $row1["$y_axis"] ?>', null, new Date(2015, 0, <?php echo $count ?>),daysToMilliseconds(<?php echo $count ?>),  <?php echo $count++ ?>,  <?php
                                if($temp=='null') {
                                    ?>null
                                    <?php
                                    }else{
                                      echo '"'.$temp.'"';
                                    }  ?>],
                            <?php 
                            $temp = $row1["$x_axis"];
                            } ?>
                        ]);

                    <?php }else{ ?>
                        data.addColumn('string', '<?php echo $x_axis ?>');
                        data.addColumn('number', '<?php echo $y_axis ?>');
                        data.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'style' });
                        data.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip'});


                        data.addRows([
                        <?php
                        $count = 1;
                        while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()){


                            // print_r($row1);
                            // echo $x_axis.' '.$row1["$x_axis"].' '.$y_axis.' '.$row1["$y_axis"];
                            if($count > 10)
                                $count = 1;


                            ?>



                            ['<?php echo $row1["$x_axis"] ?>',<?php echo $row1["$y_axis"] ?>,'<?php echo $colors[$count++] ?>', '<?php $float = floatval($row1["$y_axis"]); if($float && intval($float) != $float && strlen($float) > 3 && strpos($row1["$y_axis"],"-") == false && strpos($key,"sgd") !== false){ echo $row1["$x_axis"]; echo " : " ; $yourval = number_format($row1["$y_axis"],2); echo "$".$yourval;} elseif ($float && intval($float) == $float && strlen($float) > 3){echo $row1["$x_axis"]; echo " : " ; echo number_format($row1["$y_axis"],2);} else{echo $row1["$x_axis"]; echo " : " ; echo number_format($row1["$y_axis"]);}?>' ],
                        <?php } ?>
                        ]);

                    <?php } ?>

                    // Set chart options
                    var options = {height: 'auto',
                                   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          chartArea: {
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
                },
                                   width : 'auto',
                                   title: '<?php echo $row["graph_title"];?>',
                                   tooltip : {trigger: 'selection', isHtml: true},
                                   is3D: true,
                                   legend: 'none',
                                   vAxis: {title: '<?php echo $row ["y_axis"] ?>'}, //yaxis
                                   hAxis: {title: '<?php echo $row ["x_axis"] ?>'}, //xaxis
                                   bar: { groupWidth: '40%' },
                                   vAxis: {format: '#,###.##'}
                               };



                    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                    <?php if($row['type_of_graph']==1) { ?>
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('container1'));
                    <?php }elseif($row['type_of_graph']==2){ ?>
                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('container1'));
                    <?php }elseif($row['type_of_graph']==3){ ?>
                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('container1'));
                    <?php }elseif($row['type_of_graph']==4){ ?>
                    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('container1'));
                    <?php }elseif($row['type_of_graph']==5){ ?>
                    var chart = new google.visualization.WordTree(document.getElementById('container1'));
                    <?php }elseif($row['type_of_graph']==6){ ?>
                    var chart = new google.visualization.GanttChart(document.getElementById('container1'));
                    <?php } ?>
                    chart.draw(data, options);

                    //set default section for one column
                    chart.setSelection([{row:0, column:1}]);
                  }
            </script>
            <div id="container1" style="width:100%;"></div>


            <style>div.google-visualization-tooltip { background-color: #CCCC99; font-weight:bold;border:2px solid darkgray;}</style>


                <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:2%;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="width:100%;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Select Column :</td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="select_column" id="select_column" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">NULL</option>
                                        <?php
                                            //generate query and doing a search 
                                            $query = $row['sql_statement'];
                                            $result = $conn_temp->query($query);
                                            while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc())
                                            {
                                                foreach((array)$row1 as $key=>$val)
                                                { ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo  $key ?>"><?php echo $key ?></option>
                                                <?php }
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>Enter value to search :</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="select_value" id="select_value" value="" class="form-control">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <hr>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTable_table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php
                                        //generate query
                                        $query = $row['sql_statement'];
                                        $result = $conn_temp->query($query);
                                        while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc())
                                        {
                                            foreach((array)$row1 as $key=>$val)
                                            { 
                                                ?>
                                                <th><?php echo $key ?></th>
                                            <?php
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                    //generate query
                                    $query = $row['sql_statement'];
                                    $result = $conn_temp->query($query);
                                    while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc())
                                    { ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <?php
                                            foreach((array)$row1 as $key=>$val) //generate all the columns
                                            { ?>

                                                <th><?php 

                                                $float = floatval($val);//checking for decimal if it is present 

                                                if($float && intval($float) != $float && strlen($float) > 3  ){ //checking for the criteria to place decimalpoints


                                                    $yourval = number_format($float,2); //placing it in 2 decimal points
                                                    echo $yourval;


                                                } 

                                                elseif($float && intval($float) != $float && strlen($float) > 3 && strpos($val,'-') == false){ //checking for the criteria to place decimalpoints

                                                    $yourval = number_format($float,2); //placing it in 2 decimal points
                                                    echo $yourval;

                                                } 

                                                elseif ($float && intval($float) == $float && strlen($float) > 3 && strpos($val,'-') == false){

                                                    $yourval = number_format($float,2); 
                                                    echo $yourval;
                                                } 

                                                else{

                                                    echo $val; //if does not fit the criteria then place just show the value

                                                } 
                                                ?></th>
                                            <?php
                                            } ?>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <style>
  #dataTable_table thead {
    background-color:#D2DCDF;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border:2px inset #D2DCDF;
    padding:5px;
  }
  </style>

    <link href="scripts/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="scripts/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script>
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(//search portion for graphs
            function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
                var select_value = $('#select_value').val();
                var select_column = $('#select_column').val();
                var column_index = '';
                //var column = data[1] || 0; // use data for the age column
                if ( select_value == '' || select_column == '' )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    //get the column name of data table
                    var column = 0;
                    $('#dataTable_table thead tr th').each(function(){
                        if( $(this).text() == select_column.toString())
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        column = column + 1;
                    });
                    column = data[column] || 0;
                    if(column!==0 && column.toLowerCase().indexOf(select_value.toString().toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        );



        $(document).ready( function () {
          $('#dataTable_table').dataTable( {
            "bSort": false
          } );
        } );

        $.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var  table = $('#dataTable_table').DataTable();
            $('#select_value').keyup( function() {
                table.draw();
            });
        });


    </script>



</body>
```